# excel fix value for chart

Tags: excel, charts

i have some data in excel 2007 and draw a line chart with them, so i have two series: one for data and a series for average to compare data with average. now i want to add a fix value for series 2(average) to draw average line in chart.

```
series 2(average) value ={Sheet3!$I$18,Sheet3!$I$18,Sheet3!$I$18}
the average value is in i18 cell
```

but it has error about "the formula you typed contains an Error"
any body to help me to draw average line?

```
my data are in d24:d26 cells
and average is in i18
```

if i use const number it's working like below:

```
series 2(average) value ={5003,5003,5003}
```

but i want read the series value from cells, which on change the average number(i18 cell) the charge series(average line) change too.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cell G24 enter

=$I$18

Copy to cells G25 and G26.

Now select cells G24 to G26 and copy. Select the chart and use Paste Special. Accept the defaults. The chart now has the average line.

By definition, a line needs at least two data points, beginning and end. You could leave cell G25 empty, but then you must tell Excel to connect the line between empty cells. That setting is in the Select Data dialog behind the button "Hidden and empty cells". With that approach you can avoid duplicating the average value for each data point.

Here is a screenshot with such a setup.

[image]

Edit: It can be done with just one cell but it's a lot more preparation.

- Add the single cell to the chart as a new series.
- Change that series to XY Scatter
- Edit the series values, set X to 1, set Y to the cell value
- add horizontal error bars to the average series, with settings being Plus, No Cap, Fixed value (count the number of data points in the line and enter that as the fixed value)
- format the error bar line as desired and format the data marker to be invisible. Here is how this can look:

[image]

Comment: thank u teylyn . it's working an i tried it before. the problem is that i just want to use one cell value and define it on series value! . is any way do it?

Comment: I added another technique to my answer.

Comment: teylyn how can i do the last step? i can't find it!

Comment: teylyn, i select the average series and in layout tab in analysis group, select error bars ->more error bars options to add step 4. am i right?